# Help understanding part of slipping and rotation problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics, torque, rotational-kinematics, rotation

> A disk of mass $M$ and radius $R$ is initially rotating at an angular velocity of $\omega$. While rotating, it is placed on a horizontal surface whose coefficient of friction is $\mu = 0.5$. How long will it take for the disk to stop rotating?

Someone had solved the problem the following way:

> $$
> \mathrm{df}=\mu \mathrm{mg} \cdot \frac{2 \pi \mathrm{xdx}}{\pi \mathrm{R}^{2}}=\frac{2 \mu \mathrm{mgx}}{\mathrm{R}^{2}} \mathrm{dx}\\  
> \Rightarrow \mathrm{d} \tau=\mathrm{xdf}=\frac{2 \mu \mathrm{mgx}^{2} \mathrm{dx}}{\mathrm{R}^{2}}\\ 
> \Rightarrow \int \mathrm{d} \tau=\frac{2 \mu \mathrm{mg}}{\mathrm{R}^{2}} \int_{0}^{R} \mathrm{x}^{2} \mathrm{~d} \mathrm{x} \\\text{Again}, \quad \tau=\frac{2}{3} \mu \mathrm{mgR}\\ 
> \tau=\mathrm{I} \alpha=\frac{1}{2} \mathrm{~m} \mathrm{R}^{2} \alpha\\ 
> \Rightarrow \alpha=\frac{4}{3} \frac{\mu \mathrm{g}}{\mathrm{R}}\\
> \alpha \mathrm{t}=\omega \Rightarrow \mathrm{t}=\frac{\omega}{\alpha}=\frac{3 \omega \mathrm{R}}{4 \mathrm{\mu g}} 
> $$

Unfortunately, I didn't understand the first line $\text{df} = \mu \text{mg} \cdot \dfrac{2 \pi x \text{dx}}{\pi R^2}$. Could someone please explain it to me? Or, is there any other way to solve the problem?

Comment: Please format any mathematics using LaTeX; using images for mathematics is looked frowned upon.

Comment: Hello! You might find this helpful: [Image equation to TeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/116863/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the object were sliding the friction force would be $\mu N$ where $N$ is the normal contact force.  $N=Mg$ so the first part $\mu Mg$ is to do with the total friction force.

The problem is that it's rotating, and torque that slows the disc (from a given part of the disc) depends on the the distance from the middle that each part of the disc is.

For example a square cm area at the edge has more slowing effect than a square cm near the middle.

To get things ready for the later integration the person has found a formula for the force from a circular segment a distance $x$ from the middle, of width $dx$ and circumference $2\pi x$.  The area of this is $2\pi x dx$

So the second part of the formula is needed to find the right fraction of the total friction force that should be allocated to the circular segment at radius $x$, that's why it's also been divided by the total area $\pi R^2$.

Then the later integration moves onto finding the torque from that segment and that depends on the distance from the middle, hence the extra $x$...